# What would a laser gun realistically look like?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction, weapons

I'm writing a science fiction book where laser gun are a common weapon. The idea being that the combatative capabilities come more from the laser ionizing the air and reacting with whatever it 'hits' (melting/subliming any solid object it comes in contacting with). So I was wondering what a laser gun would look like. Would it look like regular pistol or what we see in Star Trek? Or would it look completely different then those two examples?

Comment: We cannot make a sufficiently powerful portable laser. As a consequence, we have absolutely no idea how such a weapon would look like, because the technology to make it is yet to be invented. (Our best currently existing [laser weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_High_Energy_Laser) look very much like [naval cannons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_High_Energy_Laser), are most definitely not man-portable and need an entire ship to power them.) VTC as fundamentally opinion based: in your book you should make them look they way the plot needs them to look.

Comment: See for reference: [could laser or other energy-bolt shooting guns ever practically replace regular handheld guns, what are the obstacles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6384/could-laser-or-other-energy-bolt-shooting-guns-ever-practically-replace-regula).

Comment: If they're the same lasers science is familiar with, then probably something like [this](https://youtu.be/IzUoe-9bKa0).

Comment: Writer to writer --- seriously, if you're writing a book, please do work on basic writing skills like description, grammar, spelling and following the Publisher's guidelines for publication. Readers ***WILL*** judge you (and often harshly) by how you present yourself in print. The above is not your best example of your writing I hope.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a common laser pointer.

The only difference between that and a laser weapon is its power.
Your weapon would have to:

- have a large enough power supply.
- be large enough for the electronics to handle the power.
- be able to dispose of the heat produced by the far less than 100% efficient conversion of stored energy into laser light.
- be small and light enough to be easily carried and aimed.
  How that design is implemented, and what it looks like, is up to your imagination.

But the real problem is how it would be used:

- Is it going to cut people in half? Give them a severe sunburn? Blind them? Or what?
- Is it going to be powerful enough that a 100 millisecond shot will be sufficient,
  or will it have to be aimed at the target for several seconds?
- Are misses (or shots right through the target) going to kill bystanders a block or two away?
- What happens if your target is wearing a retro-reflective suit?

There's a good reason that Star Wars blasters aren't lasers.
They solve the above problems by shooting at a relatively slow velocity and quickly dissipating after passing the target.
They of course are pure sci-fi, meant to look impressive to the audience while actually being relatively useless.

A standard bullet-firing handgun would be far simpler, far more effective, and far more useful than a hand-held laser weapon.

Advanced technology should either be the macguffin that *drives* the plot, or be something that naturally *derives from* the plot.
Introducing something, simply because it seems like a neat thing to have, is not good writing.

Comment: A fourth characteristic that I encounter all the time when working with lasers and is _very_ important: it would have to have a means of dumping all the waste heat generated by the laser.

Comment: @jdunlop, right. I think I considered that part of the "handle the power" point, but yes, it's worth explicit mention.  Thanks.

Comment: Re: "*What happens if your target is wearing a retro-reflective suit?*", the answer is that any laser powerful enough to be used as a weapon burns right through it instantly.  There's a well known YouTube video where an industrial laser cutter cuts out individual mirrors out of a sheet with the reflective side facing the laser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-VlVmBZGI4

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on how much realism you want.  Some random thoughts:

- The primary laser technologies that are candidates for generating high power either use lots of electricity (semiconductor solid-state lasers) or chemicals (chemical lasers), so there would likely be a cable coming off the laser itself to a backpack or other power/fuel source.
- Lasers have limited efficiency in converting its input to laser energy.  Even if laser efficiency was around 90% (and a quick scan of the literature shows the best known efficiency today is much, much less than that), an enormous amount of waste heat would still be released, meaning some sort of cooling method would be required.  So one would expect an additional tube to a backpack for recirculating coolant and very large heat sinks.
- Unlike a conventional firearm, the aim and focus of a laser can be electro-mechanically shifted using optics.  So instead of aiming a laser weapon directly, one might imagine future computer assisted aiming where one simply designates the target using AR glasses and simply points the laser weapon in the right general direction.  (In fact, with computer assisted aiming, the person designating the target could even be someone other than the person carrying the laser.)  This removes the need for parts of the firearm used for sighting along its barrel.
- Length of a weapon's barrel no longer corresponds to power or accuracy beyond a certain minimum.  Note that current experimental laser weapons look like a fat, short-ish telescope rather than a cannon or artillery piece.
- The optics are rather delicate, of course.  One would expect a cover on the laser aperture when not in use.  The weapon itself would be need to be in a shock resistant chassis or frame to prevent a drop from knocking the optics out of alignment.

My personal imagination of a laser weapon that might exist 50 years from now would be something shaped like a M3 "Carl Gustaf" recoilless rifle connected to to a large backpack providing power and cooling.  [EDIT]  For clarification, the point of the analogy with the M3 is purely for its general shape: it is relatively short, has a large diameter (to hold the optics), and has an enlargement at the rear (to hold the laser head and cooling) and is operated as a shoulder-fired weapon (unavoidable because of its size and shape).

Comment: RE recoilless: Photons do carry momentum, so there is recoil, albeit probably not noticable.

Comment: Carl... oh! a "bazooka".

Comment: The "recoilless rifle" isn't actually recoilless, it just spews out its recoil in form of exhaust, over the shoulder of the operator. With a laser weapon, you don't have that exhaust problem, so you need neither a stock, nor do you need to make sure that the end doesn't point at the operator's body.

Comment: @Philipp you'll find that stocks have existed on crossbows for a couple of thousand years, and those weapons are not particularly known for backblast or recoil. Stocks aid in holding and aiming.

Comment: > Length of a weapon's barrel no longer corresponds to power or accuracy, i maybe misremembering but I thought the length of the optical cavity actually does effect both the power and the accuracy

Comment: @StarfishPrime https://archeryandbow.com/do-crossbows-have-recoil/ While crossbows have less recoil, they still have enough that accuracy is affected when it's not properly absorbed through the shoulder stock.

Comment: @jk. the biggest factor is the diameter of the objective lens, which strongly limits performance of the optics. Everything else in the optical bit is amenable to being squidged down to some extent. Of course, the nature of the bit that does the actual _lasing_ is quite a different matter...

Comment: @StarfishPrime I tried to find some arguments regarding whether or not laser weapons need shoulder stocks by looking at equipment for pro laser tag. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much of a market for laser tag guns which look like professional sports equipment. It seems to me like those laser tag guns which have shoulder stocks usually closely resemble the aesthetics of real-world firearms, including ridiculous non-functional parts like fake magazines. Those which look more like toys rarely have shoulder stocks. But laser tag is of course usually played on rather short distances.

Comment: @Philipp its an interesting sort of problem; most big optical systems in the real world seem to have bipods, tripods or other kinds of rest, and devices that are intended to be used on the move have other operational requirements that weapons may not have (smooth panning, for example). SLR shoulder stocks do exist, but photojournalists doing a "run and gun" style of photography don't use them... though like laser tag they're operating at close ranges too. And so on...

Comment: @Philipp from my relatively limited experience (with both cameras and firearms), I'd say that a lightweight folding stock would be a useful thing for aiming at more distant targets. The ability to brace the device, without having to rely on your hands alone to keep it steady, is very valuable. Other firmer supports would be preferable, but aren't always practical.